# How to install Certbot via Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

This is how I install Certbot in a Bash script:

```
apt-get update -y && add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot -y && apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade nginx python-certbot-nginx -y
```

---

That's the playbook syntax I found to install Nginx in default conf:

```
- hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    become: true

tasks:
    - name: install nginx
    apt: pkg=nginx state=installed update_cache=true
```

Is there no Ansible task to install Certbot as well, instead the above "heavier" Bash code?

Comment: Did you check ansible galaxy?

Comment: No, just heard of that from you... :)

Comment: Hmm, just ran "certbot" in the Ansible Galaxy search engine... Sadly zero results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the direct Ansible translation of your bash install script:

```
- apt_repository:
    repo: 'ppa:certbot/certbot'

- apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - nginx
    - python-certbox-nginx
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 with Ansible 2.5.1, the first 2 rows raises: ``Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed``. However, I found that adding the repo is not needed in Ubuntu 18.04. You can install it directly with ``become: yes`` and ``apt: name: python-certbot-nginx``

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 16.04 should be something like this

```
tasks
- name: Install Certbot.
  package: "name=letsencrypt state=present"
```

Or you can use a role from Github: https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-certbot

Comment: this does not install certbot

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the role mentioned does in fact install Certbot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
- name: Add certbot repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'ppa:certbot/certbot'

- name: Install Certbot's Apache package
  apt:
    name: python-certbot-apache
    state: present
```

Answer (score -1):

chipping in with ansible task to install letsencrypt certbot on debian stretch

```
---
- name: Add "stretch-backports" to APT sources (required for Certbot)
  become: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
    state: present
    update_cache: yes

- name: "Check LetsEncrypt/Certbot is installed"
  become: yes
  apt:
    name: 
      - certbot
      - python-certbot-apache # https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/3854
    state: present
    default_release: stretch-backports
    cache_valid_time: 3600
    update_cache: yes
```